# Supress output from Visual Studio output pane (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I run my Win32 project in the Visual Studio debugger, I get this huge screed of output about which DLLs were loaded, first-chance exceptions, and so on.

Is there a way that I can suppress this output?

Some day, I might want to know when 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll' was loaded, but normally I don't care. This is especially true when I'm running unit tests, and just want to be told whether any of the tests failed.

This stuff isn't output with console applications, but it is with windows applications. To give an example of what I mean, here are the first lines from the output of a recent unit-test run.

```
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\dev\MyProject\Testing\MyProject.exe', Symbols loaded.
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'
'MyProject.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'

... and on and on ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click in the output window. You'll get a popup menu where you can de-select types of messages you don't want to see (e.g. Module Load and Module Unload messages). Unfortunately, it puts all the Exception Messages together, so (at least AFAIK) you can't exclude first chance exception messages (which you rarely care about) but keep second chance exception messages (which you usually do care about).

Comment: Note because I felt stupid: you have to have selected "Show output from Debug" (aka, currently display your output you want to modify)

Comment: Is there any way to make these settings persist past visual studio restart? I'm finding that I need to deselect Module Load / Unload every time I restart the application.

Answer (score 2):

Click with right mouse button on the Output window and switch off "Module Load Messages".