# Make Visual Studio ignore exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight

I'm using exceptions to validate a control's input in Silverlight 4. When I throw an invalid input exception, VS 2010 displays the popup and stops the program. I ignore this and resume the program, and everything continues fine (since the exception is used to signal a validation error.) Is there a way to mark that one exception as ignored?

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86955/Silverlight-4-Data-Validation-Tip-of-the-Day-Part-.aspx).

Comment: Nearly an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689065/supress-output-from-visual-studio-output-pane-c/2689187#2689187 (and my answer applies equally here). I'd advise against using exceptions for validating user input -- if anything, correct input is the exception and mistakes the rule, not the other way around.

Comment: I know. But this appears to be the way Silverlight does it. (Or so it seems. I'm new to SL.)

Comment: You could consider the `Try*` approach, like `int.TryParse("123", ref result)` that returns a `bool` indicating if the operation succeeded.

Comment: @Rosharch is right - validation controls on Silverlight work via exceptions, which can be quite annoying unless you disable breaking on them.

Comment: @NickHeiner If you like my answer can you please accept, I'm trying to get my profile ready and green would look nice on my developer story. Thanks! - JB

Answer (score 19):

Debug -> Exceptions -> Uncheck

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to disable it directly from the popup.

Answer (score 5):

Menu, Debugger, Exceptions...

In that dialog, you can remove the checkmark in the 'thrown' column for one exception, of for a whole namespace. You can add your own. etc.etc.

Comment: This was useful information and allowed us to create a custom exception to reset FPU registers from using an unmanaged dll and be able to debug as normal. Very handy!

Answer (score 5):

I got `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden()]` to work if I also selected

Debug > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code (Managed only).

I access the Excel object model a lot, and I really like to be able to run the debugger and catching all exceptions, since my code normally is exception less. However, the Excel API throws a lot of exceptions.

```
// [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]  works too
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden()]
private static Excel.Range TrySpecialCells(Excel.Worksheet sheet, Excel.XlCellType cellType)
{
    try
    {
        return sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(cellType);
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work anymore, see [this dev blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Answer (score 2):

When you run Visual Studio in debug mode, there are Exception Setting on the bottom tool bar. Once you click it, there are all type exceptions. Uncheck exceptions that you want. For the Custom exception you made for this project, they are located in Common Language Runtime Exceptions, at very bottom. Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable some throw block by surrounding in the block

```
#if !DEBUG
       throw new Exception();
/// this code will be excepted in the debug mode but will be run in the release 
#endif
```

Comment: Won't this stop the exception from being thrown? I want it to be thrown, I just don't want VS to stop the application and pop up that box.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this above the property that throws the exception seems like it should work but apparently doesn't: 
`[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden()]`:

```
    private String name;

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden()]
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Please enter a name.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio 2015 onward there is an Exception Settings window for this.

Debug > Windows > Exception Settings