# how can I suppress output from Tests window after a build?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, mstest

I'm working with a large solution (90+ projects). When I build it, if the build succeeds, I get about 50 lines in the Output window that say things like

`UTA050: Test XYZ.ABC.GEF has the Ignore attribute. Ignoring test.`

Fine. But the obnoxious thing is that it takes a very long time for all this output to show up, like 30-45s. I'm building before a checkin, so this is just a bit annoying as I have to wait for this output window to do its thing before I can check in.

Is there any way to suppress this output? [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689065/supress-output-from-visual-studio-output-pane-c) doesn't answer it.

Comment: Is it also running non-ignored tests between each of these warnings?  If so, your best bet is just to turn off tests.  Plus, having to wait 40 seconds before a checkin is comparing a flea to an elephant, unless you like to do dozens of 1 line checkins...

Comment: @Merlyn No, it's not running tests. I have to wait for this after every build, so it adds up. I typically only build the project that I'm working on but often need to build the full solution.

Comment: I tried building a test project with an ignore attribute and did not observe any message in the output window. To understand your question better, can you share which version of VS you are using (VS 2010 or 2008 or 2005) and what types of test projects (C#, native, VB) are there?

Comment: @Aseem: I'm using Mstest projects in C# and VS2008. When I build a test project that has one regular test and one Ignore test I get: `UTA050: Test MyProject.MyTest.IgnoreThisTest has the Ignore attribute. Ignoring test.` in the Output:Tests window. No big deal, but when I'm building a solution that has 90+ projects, it forces me to wait for 30s or so after every build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that this writing to Output:Tests is a side effect of having the Test View panel open when building. The solution seems to be to make sure that that panel is closed when doing a build.